# PHP: How to reset a global variable before each use in function containing eval()

Tags: php, function, global-variables, eval, global

I have the following code in a website.

```
$magic_number_output = 'The magic number is: $magic_number';

function show_magic_number($magic_number) {
  global $magic_number_output;

  eval("\$magic_number_output = \"$magic_number_output\";");

  echo '
  ' . $magic_number_output;

}
```

The variable `$magic_number_output` is being set in a separate PHP file, then referenced using global inside a function as there will be different versions of this variable for different languages. `$magic_number` is passed into the function and this is replaced in the variable by using `eval()`. However, when the function is called more than once, the `$magic_number` does not change from the first value sent to the function. For example, if called like this:

```
show_magic_number(5);
show_magic_number(2000);
```

...the output is like this:

```
The magic number is: 5
The magic number is: 5
```

...when I would like it to be this:

```
The magic number is: 5
The magic number is: 2000
```

Obviously, I've misunderstood how `global` and `eval()` works and have tried searching for answers and experimenting but am simply too much of a noob to figure out a solution. I thought there might have been some way of resetting the global variable each time so that it doesn't continue to reference the `$magic_number` (i.e. `5`) sent to the function the first time.

Can anyone suggest a way around this?

Comment: Why are you doing it this way? Why not just set the $magic_number_output inside the function?

Comment: As explained, the variable $magic_number_output is being set in a separate PHP file as there will be different versions of this variable for different languages. A single file is used per language to contain strings used throughout the site.

Comment: By the way, you should really consider not using `eval()` as it's quite bad and evil. In your case, it seems overly complicated...

Comment: Can you suggest an alternative? I acknowledge that eval() is not safe when user input is passed through, but in this case, only values set by my own code will be passed to it.

Comment: $magic_number_output = "The magic number is: $magic_number"; //should work fine.. not sure why you need the eval()

Comment: Magic? Global? Eval? I'm outta here!

Comment: Thanks so much everyone. Your prompt comments and solutions have been most appreciated.

Comment: Have you been trying to make the most appalling php code known to man?  I think you forgot to add `goto` ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.  It will at least get rid of the `eval()`

```
$magic_number_output = 'The magic number is: $magic_number';

function show_magic_number($magic_number) {
  global $magic_number_output;

  $output=$magic_number_output;
  echo str_replace('$magic_number',$magic_number,$output);
}
```

Comment: Thanks; this is great. So simple and it does the job.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `eval`, take a look at the [sprintf](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) function:

```
$magic_number_output = 'The magic number is: %d';

function show_magic_number($magic_number) {
  global $magic_number_output;
  echo sprintf($magic_number_output, $magic_number);
}
```

Comment: no, `sprintf` is bad, `eval` is better, it makes code more dynamic